# indexoutofboundsexception in program

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Good afternoon, I am adapting this code To Do a search based on Automaton. The Automaton will FIND dates in the source codes of the web pages and will Show these dates on the netbeans console. It is happening a java error lang on Line 122 of buscapadraoweb package.

```
package buscapadraoweb;

import buscaweb.CapturaRecursosWeb;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    // busca char em vetor e retorna indice
    public static int get_char_ref (char[] vet, char ref ){
        for (int i=0; i<vet.length; i++ ){
            if (vet[i] == ref){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // busca string em vetor e retorna indice
    public static int get_string_ref (String[] vet, String ref ){
        for (int i=0; i<vet.length; i++ ){
            if (vet[i].equals(ref)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }



    //retorna o próximo estado, dado o estado atual e o símbolo lido
    public static int proximo_estado(char[] alfabeto, int[][] matriz,int estado_atual,char simbolo){
        int simbol_indice = get_char_ref(alfabeto, simbolo);
        if (simbol_indice != -1){
            return matriz[estado_atual][simbol_indice];
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /*
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //instancia e usa objeto que captura código-fonte de páginas Web
        CapturaRecursosWeb crw = new CapturaRecursosWeb();
        crw.getListaRecursos().add("http://www.mercadolivre.com");
        ArrayList<String> listaCodigos = crw.carregarRecursos();

        String codigoHTML = listaCodigos.get(0);

        //mapa do alfabeto
        char[] alfabeto = new char[11];
        alfabeto[0] = '-';
        alfabeto[1] = '0';
        alfabeto[2] = '1';
        alfabeto[3] = '2';
        alfabeto[4] = '3';
        alfabeto[5] = '4';
        alfabeto[6] = '5';
        alfabeto[7] = '6';
        alfabeto[8] = '7';
        alfabeto[9] = '8';
        alfabeto[10] = '9';



        //mapa de estados
        String[] estados = new String[10];
        estados[0] = "q0";
        estados[1] = "q1";
        estados[2] = "q3";
        estados[3] = "q4";
        estados[4] = "q5";
        estados[5] = "q6";
        estados[6] = "q7";
        estados[7] = "q8";
        estados[8] = "q9";
        estados[9] = "q10";



        String estado_inicial = "q0";

        //estados finais
        String[] estados_finais = new String[1];
        estados_finais[0] = "q10";

        //tabela de transição de AFD para reconhecimento números de dois dígitos
        int[][] matriz = new int[3][11];
        //transições de q0
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
        //transições de q1
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
        //transições de q2

        // ************** ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here ***************
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
        //transições de q3
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
        //transições de q4
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q4")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '-')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q5");
        //transições de q5
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
        //transições de q6
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
        //transições de q7
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q7")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '-')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q8");
        //transições de q8
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
        //transições de q9
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
        //transições de q10
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = -1;
        matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '-')] = -1;



        int estado = get_string_ref (estados, estado_inicial);
        int estado_anterior = -1;
        ArrayList<String> palavras_reconhecidas = new ArrayList();


        String palavra = "";

        //varre o código-fonte de um código
        for (int i=0; i<codigoHTML.length(); i++){

            estado_anterior = estado;
            estado = proximo_estado(alfabeto, matriz, estado, codigoHTML.charAt(i));
            //se o não há transição
            if (estado == -1){
                //pega estado inicial
                estado = get_string_ref(estados, estado_inicial);
                // se o estado anterior foi um estado final
                if (get_string_ref(estados_finais, estados[estado_anterior]) != -1){
                    //se a palavra não é vazia adiciona palavra reconhecida
                    if ( ! palavra.equals("")){
                        palavras_reconhecidas.add(palavra);
                    }
                    // se ao analisar este caracter não houve transição
                    // teste-o novamente, considerando que o estado seja inicial
                    i--;
                }
                //zera palavra
                palavra = "";

            }else{
                //se houver transição válida, adiciona caracter a palavra
                palavra += codigoHTML.charAt(i);
            }
        }


        //foreach no Java para exibir todas as palavras reconhecidas
        for (String p: palavras_reconhecidas){
            System.out.println (p);
        }


}
```

I tried to change this in the code( number of states of automate) but the error still appearing.

```
int[][] matriz = new int[10][11];
```

The error mesage (line 122):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at buscapadraoweb.Main.main(Main.java:122)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please show the full error message and indicate which line(s) cause it.

Comment: Line 122...I edited, the error mesage is on the last line

Comment: Great, so which line is line 122 of Main.java?

Comment: matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");

Comment: I found my error... it was missing "q2" on the string array named "estados"... now another error appears..

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the solution. Accept the correct answer (which you've done already) is enough to do.

Comment: Building on what @Tom said, if you have another question, please write another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"q2" isn't in your `estados` array, so get_string_ref is returning -1.